# Looping through a table and append information of that table to another file

Tags: linux, bash, loops, sh

This is my first post and im fairly new to bash coding. 
We ran some Experiments where i work and for plotting it in gnuplot we need to append a reaction label to a Result.

We have a file that looks like this:

```
G135b   CH2O+HCO=O2+C2H3
R020b   2CO+H=OH+C2O
R021b   2CO+O=O2+C2O
```

and a Result-file (which i cant access right now, sorry) where the first column of shown file is the same, followed by multiple values. They are not in the same order. 
Now i want to loop through the Result-file and take the value of the first column, search for it in the shown file and append the reactionlabel to that line.

1. How can i loop through all the lines of the resulting file and take the  value of the first column in a temporary variable?
   I want to use this variable like this:

   ```
   grep -r '^$var' shownfile | awk '{print $2}'
   ```

   (Gives something back like this: CH2O+HCO=O2+C2H3)
2. How can i append the result of that line to the Result-file?

**Edit:** I also wrote a Script to go from a file that looks like this:

`G135b :   0.178273     C H 2 O + H C O = O 2 + C 2 H 3`

to this:

`G135b   CH2O+HCO=O2+C2H3`

which is:

```
#!/bin/bash
file=$(pwd)
cd $file
# echo "$file"
cut -f1,3 $file/newfile >>tmpfile
sed -i "s/://g" tmpfile
sed -i "s/ //g" tmpfile
cp tmpfile newfile
```

3. How do i execute the cut command inside a file? Like -i for sed. My workaround is pretty ugly because it creates another file in the current directory.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

`join` command would work here which would perform inner join on 2 files wrt 1st column of each(by default).

```
$ cat data
G135b   CH2O+HCO=O2+C2H3
R020b   2CO+H=OH+C2O
R021b   2CO+O=O2+C2O

$ cat result_file
G135b   a b c
R020b   a b
R021b   a b x y z

$ join data result_file
G135b CH2O+HCO=O2+C2H3 a b c
R020b 2CO+H=OH+C2O a b
R021b 2CO+O=O2+C2O a b x y z
```

Comment: the problem is, that the files are not sorted so i have to do some kind of searching for the equivalent first column in the first file.

Comment: @Thunfisch you can sort and then use join like this: `join <(sort -k 1 data) <(sort -k 1 result_file)`

Comment: I just checked on the joint command: I dont think this could work as we have some Reaction in the Result-file that are not existent in the Label File. So after the first case of that would pop up all the labels would be messed up

Comment: @Thunfisch no it wont, it would output only matching records

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`, it would be something like:

```
NR == FNR { data[$1] = $2; next; }
{ print $0 " " data[$1]; }
```

Save that in a file called `reactions.awk`, then call `awk -f reactions.awk shownfile resultfile`.

Comment: Just to get it right: this first checks if the line Numbers of both files are the same and then what does data[$1] = $2 ? Is the next for telling awk that there is another action to perform? 
Print $0 is telling awk to print the current object its working on but what do the " " after that do? 
Thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

```
awk  '{a[$1]=a[$1]$2} END{for (i in a){print i,a[i]}}' file1 file2
```

Comment: What exactly is a? 
The pattern is: if row 1 of file 1 is equal to row 1 of file 2, read the line and at the end of that reading, do: print current linenumber and a of current line
Did i get it right ?

Comment: 'a' will collect the data from two files appended irrespective of line-number and print it. 1st column followed by appended data